# Arba'a Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred fourteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Megila 15b

ורמי בר אבא אמר כולן מאתים ושמונה הוו שנאמר ורוב בניו **ורוב בגימטריא מאתן וארביסר** הוו אמר רב נחמן בר יצחק ורב כתיב

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6357/shemona-umatayim-mi-yodeya/6358#6358

Answer (score 1):

The Chashmonaim began to rule (and according to some sources, the miracle of Chanukah happened) 214 years after the building of the second Beis Hamikdash (3408-3622).